# Is there a way to enter greek letters in Wolfram Workbench 2.0?

Tags: eclipse, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to enter and use greek letters in a .m file in Wolfram Workbench 2.0?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp), but could you just use [`\[Alpha]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/ref/character/Alpha.html), `\[CapitalAlpha]` etc...?

Comment: @Simon ! I rarely see you these days.  I miss your presence.  I hope you find time to visit more often soon.  (At [Mathematica.SE] I mean.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! I miss spending time on the Mma.SE site...

Comment: Thanks Simon - I have not found anything on this in the Workbench documentation either.  It would be awesome to be able to see the greek symbols in Workbench as well as Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there really is no way to actually use greek symbols inside of Wolfram Workbench 2.0.

The best solution is the one recommended by Simon (use [Alpha], [Epsilon], etc.)

When the code from Workench is pasted into Mathematica (as a check), the symbols are rendered as greek.

It would really be nice to have the ability to see greek symbols in Wolfram Workbench.  This would really improve the readability of code.